# How to fix log error of ElasticSearch package?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ElasticSearch package version 7.15.0. Every time I see an error like
[image]

Following file from these path we can see:

```
Log.prototype.error = function (e) {
  if (this.listenerCount('error')) {
    return this.emit('error', e instanceof Error ? e : new Error(e));
  }
};
```

Why does this error occur? Does it need to be corrected?